# operator== not working in template function

Tags: c++, struct, stl

I am writing a template function which takes in a vector and a struct, and inserts that struct into the vector. If there is a duplicate struct in the vector however,the function will not insert the struct because the values must all be unique. In order to do this, I am using the find function of the STL library, and analyzing the return value using the `operator==`. However, I am getting this error every time I try and compile:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'OneToOneMap' and'OneToOneMap')|
```

My template function can be seen below:

```
template<typename Type> void AddToList(vector<Type> add_to, Type to_insert){
    bool contains_element = *find( add_to.begin(), add_to.end(), to_insert) == *add_to.end() ? false:true;

    if(contains_element){
        cout << "Element is already in list" << endl;
    }else{
        add_to.push_back(to_insert);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated programming languages.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well I assume you haven't overloaded the `operator==` for the class `OneToOneMap`?

Comment: `*add_to.end()` is wrong too

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear however I suspect you haven't overloaded the `operator==` in the class/struct `OneToOneMap` which you are trying to compare in your code. Assuming this is a user-defined type, overload this operator (and `operator!=`) as follows:

```
class OneToOneMap {

public:

    //...

    bool operator==(const OneToOneMap& _other) const {
        // do comparison based on fields
    }

    bool operator!=(const OneToOneMap& _other) const {
        return !(*this == _other);
    }

};
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot to do that. Is there any way to circumvent having to do this? This function compares lists composed of many types of structs so if there is any alternative to writing operator overloads for all of those structs it would be a big time/code saver

Comment: Yes, the solution provided by @iksemyonov is better as this allows direct comparison of the iterators rather than the types.

Comment: @kenb see my answer above. With find, you compare the iterators, not the values.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Ineed, you need to provide an overload for the type that you want to use `std::find<T>()` on! The reason is that of course the function needs a way to compare the container elements to find out if they're equal or not. Provide an overload for the `bool T::operator==(const T& other)` as ArchbishopOfBanterbury has noticed.

(To be more exact, comparison using the `bool operator==(...)` is used when the user has not provided another predicate to compare the elements, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

**Original answer:**

Remove the unnecessary dereference operators `*` when comparing iterators:

```
bool contains_element = find( add_to.begin(), add_to.end(), to_insert) == add_to.end() ? false:true;
```

You don't need the `false : true` either, since the comparison returns a `bool`:

```
bool contains_element = find( add_to.begin(), add_to.end(), to_insert) == add_to.end();
```

The logic is that the `std::find<T>()` function returns an iterator, and you compare that iterator to the `vector<T>::end()` iterator, i.e. the "null" iterator, to check if `find<T>()` has been able to find anything or not. You don't need to compare the `T` values themselves.

Comment: thank you for catching that error as well @ikseniymyonov. The same error pops up again however, and I am not quite sure why. It appears that I still have to overload the == operator for some reason.

Comment: @kenb see the updated answer, and sorry for the misleading first attempt at answering this.